# [NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios

I have used three picker view in a view controller and my code for picker view data source

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if (pickerView == _pickerMPurity)
    {
        return [myObject count];
    }
       if (pickerView == _pickerDPurity) {
        return [myObject1 count];
    }
   if (pickerView == _pickerSize) {
        return [myObject2 count];
    }
    return YES;
   }

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:
(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if (pickerView == _pickerMPurity)
    {
        NSString *str = [[myObject objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"purityname"];
        //return [[myObject objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"purityname"];
        return str;
    }
    if (pickerView == _pickerDPurity) {
        return [myObject1 objectAtIndex:row];
    }
   if (pickerView == _pickerSize) {
        return [myObject2 objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and my problem is I'm getting the [NSNull length] error in titleForRow method.

Comment: Can you paste the log?

Comment: You mean the error log??

Comment: In which line it crashes ? And what are the values in myObject, myObject1, myObject2 contains ?

Comment: Excuse me, but why are you returning YES at the end of numberOfRowsInComponent: ? That kind of thing would be a very strong indication that your code cannot be trusted.

Comment: myObject array : {
    purityid = 00307;
    purityname = 18kt;
},
{
    purityid = 00308;
    purityname = 22k;
}

Comment: @PavithraSelvaraj Check whether arrays **myObject , myObject1 , myObject2** are empty.

Comment: no I have objects inside those arrays @KarthikSivam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

titleForRow: return type in `NSString` so you can not return 0. Yopu have to return `return nil` or `return @""`

Answer (score 2):

You obviously get that error because you send a message to an object of type NSNull. Set a breakpoint on exceptions in Xcode to find which object the message is sent to, then find out why that object is of type NSNull.

Typical reason is parsing JSON code carelessly.